# Why in R is the time when converted to a "POSIXct" "POSIXt" class reading todays date with the time when a new column is created?

Tags: date, time

The question I am answering is:

Two columns in the coyotebehav data object are labeled "date" and "time." These are EXCEL-based. Convert the date and time into three R formats, ie, 3 separate columns of new variables:
# dateLUB;      timeLUB;        datetimeLUB

The date column in the data set was converted properly with the code written below to the POSIXct class from having been a character and being in the excel format. The problem I am having is that when converting time to a POSIXct class, the column is reading todays date in addition to the time (which is already formatted properly for r).The time column is formatted this way: 13:02:09. Then the combined column reads NA for all rows since it is trying to combine two sets of dates and a time. How do I remove todays date from the timeLUB column?

So far my code reads:

```
coyote<- read.csv("coyotebehav.csv")

#vectors include, date, time, behavior, habitat type, and an ID

library(lubridate)

coyote$dateLUB <- as.POSIXct(coyote$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
class(coyote$dateLUB)

coyote$timeLUB <- as.POSIXct(coyote$time, format="%H:%M:%S")
class(coyote$timeLUB)

coyote$datetimeLUB <- as.POSIXct(paste(dateLUB, timeLUB), format 
= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: SHow some code, properly formatted. Also, what language? Add an according tag! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].